# Javascript Replacement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Okay first of all i am really sorry about my last post but i really need help here i will put a clearer code about what i really want.
I am not good at javascript so hope you please help me.

```
<span class="rating ipsType_smaller">
                <a href="" id="topic_rate_1" title="Rate topic 1 star">
                <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg rate_img"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="" id="topic_rate_2" title="Rate topic 2 stars">
                <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg rate_img"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="" id="topic_rate_3" title="Rate topic 3 stars">
                <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg rate_img"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="" id="topic_rate_4" title="Rate topic 4 stars">
                <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg rate_img"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="" id="topic_rate_5" title="Rate topic 5 stars">
                <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg rate_img"></i>
                </a>
</span>
```

okay here is html. IPB makes everything but i want to make a small edit with javascript. and no problem if it will change the html of css both are same so here is what i am thinking of:

When i hover on star 2, star 1 and star 2 will have same new class or the  will change to something new
when i hove on star 4, star 4 and all stars before star 4 will have new same class or the  will change to same new thing

and when i click on star 4 or whatever star 2 a new class will be added to this class.

can this be done through javascript?

Comment: The answer is yes, it can be done with javascript.

Comment: Better yet, it can even be done with pure CSS.

Comment: You're going to get less snide responses than the above if you try to write some code, get stuck, and ask a specific question about where you're stuck, than if you do as you're doing and ask "hey please write some code for me"

Comment: You can start from here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ and http://api.jquery.com/addclass/ and http://api.jquery.com/click/

jquery way is the easiest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can do it in JS, but also CSS only.

Assuming you want to change background,

```css
.rating:hover > a {
    background: red;         /* Set it for all elements */
}
.rating > a:hover ~ a {
    background: transparent; /* Unset it for following elements */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dwVcP/)

Comment: sorry man i am trying to make something new. i am trying to use the transition tricks for css and the active method so when i click on star 3 all the start 1 and 2 and 3 will light up or will have different background and the other two transparent. but i couldnt make it to work.
so do u have any solution or is there is any oppisite method rather than this "a:hover ~ a" so all elements before this elemnt not after this element?

Comment: @user3802001 Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: i cant as i am using font awesome and it cant appear in fiddle
this is my css for my code which i wrote up:
.rating:hover > a i::before {
    content:"\f005";
    color: #053B81;
}

    .rating > a:hover ~ a i::before {
        content:"\f006";
        color: #3A7DB9;
    }

and this is the method i am trying to use: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/17/css-click-events/
last method transition hack